# Boostrap adding pagination dots to existing carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How would it be possible to add pagination as in dots to the existing carousel for bootstrap.

Very new to this and need a little hand.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mdesignone/qXgCg/

Thanks:)

Comment: can you display your carousel code?

Comment: Hi no worries.http://jsfiddle.net/mdesignone/qXgCg/

Answer (score 0):

First create the links for the slices of your carousel. Set your id on attribute *data-slide*, and just add the dot as you like them.

See this example, to direct link on slide 1 and 2:

```
<a class="carousel-control my-carousel" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="1">·</a>
<a class="carousel-control my-carousel" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="2">·</a>
```

To style this link on your own, just define the css-class 'my-carousel'.